# Checking how CMake tags different C++ compilers

Tags: c++, cmake

Since I must link a different version of libraries depending on the compiler, I am trying to figure out how CMake tags different compilers, so that I can write the appropriate conditionals. Therefore I have put these lines at the top of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

message(STATUS "Using ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}")
```

But the above lines print just:

```
-- Using
```

Comment: Don't you mean e.g. [`${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html)? Don't forget the `CMAKE_` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for noticing.  I had copied them from "Generator expressions". But the output does not change.

Comment: And you do this *after* CMake checks the compiler? Can you please show a sample `CMakeLists.txt` file that have the problem?

Comment: That was the problem, thanks.  My understanding is that you can check the compiler only after the `project` line.  If you write an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I have edited the question to show where I was calling `message`.

Comment: @Elena, you don't need to figure it out, check the page Pileborg mentioned, which contains [the list of COMPILER_IDs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the C++ compiler first. You can either add

```
project(myProject CXX)
```

or

```
check_language(CXX)
```